# sum by rows with specific columns selected

Tags: r, sum, data.table, rows

in R data table I would like to do the sum by row according to selected columns.
Example :

```
iris = data.table(iris[,-5])
cols = c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")
```

I did it like that but I don't want to use the rowSums function :

```
    iris[, newSum := rowSums(.SD), by = .I, .SDcols = c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
```

Does someone has a trick with to just sum the rows for the columns selected easily ?

Thx

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use ``rowSums``? It's pretty highly optimised and probably the fastest way of doing so.

Comment: I really want to well understand the specific syntax of data table : .I, .SD, ...
By the way, when I selected by the rows with .I, I guessed I just have to do the sum and not the rowSums

Comment: FYI, the [tag:datatable] is for something completely different, and it clearly says *"for the data.table R package please use [tag:data.table]"*. The Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please check all of its recommendations and *read their hover text* to make sure it really applies. (I edited your tags accordingly.) Thanks!

Comment: Frankly, I cannot think of a solution that does what `rowSums` does that is (a) as declarative; (b) easier to read and therefore maintain; and/or (c) as efficient/fast as `rowSums`. While it's certainly possible to write something that mimics its behavior, too often when questions on SO that say they don't want function ABC, it is because of mistaken assumptions about said function (or the data being worked on). We may be able to suggest alternatives, but please explain why you think `rowSums` is wrong for this application. (BTW, don't use `by=.I`, it is inefficient/unnecessary here.)

Comment: Here is a simple example with juste a sum by row but how to apply a hardiest custom function by row with selected columns using data.table syntax ??

Comment: I think this is getting to the crux of the issue. You asked about *"sum by rows"* and demosntrated using `rowSums`. It would be *significantly* clearer if you said something like *"function-by-row"* and clearly stated that `myfunc` (which may be as easy to call as `rowSums`) requires arguments one row at a time.

Comment: @nimliug, any thoughts or progress? The answers have done an exhaustive (exhausting?) job demonstrating that `rowSums` is good as well as many (generally less-performant) alternatives. If my last comment is getting close to your intent, though, please [edit] your question and reword it so that your avoidance of `rowSums` is better explained. (Or just accept one and move on.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `rowSums`? It's the best way here, btw it could be better with base R:

```
iris$newSum <- rowSums(iris[, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")])
```

---

```
> iris
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width newSum
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    1.6
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    1.6
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    1.5
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    1.7
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    1.6
 ---                                                         
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3    7.5
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9    6.9
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0    7.2
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3    7.7
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8    6.9
>
```

Or if you really hate and dislike `rowSums`:

```
iris$newSum <- apply(iris[, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")], 1, sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

These don't use rowSums:

```
irisdt[, newSum := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = cols]

irisdt[, newSum := as.matrix(.SD) %*% rep(1, ncol(.SD)), .SDcols = cols]

irisdt[, newSum := eval(parse(text = paste(cols, collapse = "+")))]

irisdt[, newSum := apply(.SD, 1, sum), .SDcols = cols]

irisdt[, newSum := sum(.SD), by = 1:ncol(.SD), .SDcols = cols]

irisdt[, newSum := c(rep(1, ncol(.SD)) %*% t(.SD)), .SDcols = cols]

library(purrr)
irisdt[, newSum := pmap(.SD, sum), .SDcols = cols]

irisdt[, newSum := do.call("mapply", c(sum, .SD)), .SDcols = cols]

irisdt[, newSum := tapply(as.matrix(.SD), row(.SD), sum), .SDcols = cols]

s <- sprintf("irisdt[, newSum := %s]", paste(cols, collapse = "+"))
eval(parse(text = s))
```

### Note

```
library(data.table)
irisdt <- data.table(iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer of itself, just a comparison of those offered so far.

```r
bench::mark(
  nimliug = iris[, newSum := rowSums(.SD), by = .I, .SDcols = c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")],
  `nimliug mod` = iris[, newSum := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")],
  `U12-Forward 1` = { iris$newSum <- rowSums(iris[, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")]); iris; },
  `U12-Forward 2` = { iris$newSum <- apply(iris[, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")], 1, sum); iris; },
  `G.G 1` = iris[, newSum := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = cols],
  `G.G 2` = iris[, newSum := as.matrix(.SD) %*% rep(1, ncol(.SD)), .SDcols = cols], 
  `G.G 3` = iris[, newSum := eval(parse(text = paste(cols, collapse="+")))],
  `G.G 4` = iris[, newSum := apply(.SD, 1, sum), .SDcols = cols],
  `G.G 5` = iris[, newSum := sum(.SD), by = 1:nrow(iris), .SDcols = cols], 
  `G.G 6` = iris[, newSum := c(rep(1, ncol(.SD)) %*% t(.SD)), .SDcols = cols],
  `G.G 7` = iris[, newSum := purrr::pmap_dbl(.SD, sum), .SDcols = cols], 
  `G.G 7 mod` = iris[, newSum := do.call(mapply, c(list(sum), .SD)), .SDcols = cols],
  min_iterations = 1000
)
# # A tibble: 12 x 13
#    expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                     memory                  time             gc                  
#    <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                     <list>                  <list>           <list>              
#  1 nimliug        425.4us  541.5us     1662.    52.4KB     0     1000     0   601.83ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [9 x 3]>  <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
#  2 nimliug mod    387.2us  481.3us     1964.    52.4KB     0     1000     0   509.12ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [9 x 3]>  <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
#  3 U12-Forward 1  169.8us  221.2us     4050.    45.7KB     3.25  1248     1   308.14ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [14 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,249]> <tibble [1,249 x 3]>
#  4 U12-Forward 2    377us    503us     1837.    50.5KB     0     1000     0   544.43ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [18 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
#  5 G.G 1          320.6us  508.5us     1889.    66.2KB     1.89   999     1   528.86ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [10 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
#  6 G.G 2          360.1us  392.4us     2275.    52.4KB     0     1138     0   500.21ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [9 x 3]>  <bch:tm [1,138]> <tibble [1,138 x 3]>
#  7 G.G 3          373.7us  443.4us     2148.    34.3KB     0     1074     0   499.96ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [8 x 3]>  <bch:tm [1,074]> <tibble [1,074 x 3]>
#  8 G.G 4          540.3us  598.7us     1472.    57.3KB     1.47   999     1   678.56ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [13 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
#  9 G.G 5           4.99ms    5.5ms      177.    51.2KB     1.43   992     8      5.61s <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [11 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
# 10 G.G 6          377.5us  492.2us     1991.      56KB     0     1000     0   502.26ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [11 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
# 11 G.G 7          707.7us  866.9us     1127.    66.2KB     1.13   999     1   886.81ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [10 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
# 12 G.G 7 mod      460.1us  586.1us     1669.    54.5KB     1.67   999     1   598.62ms <data.table[,5] [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem[,3] [12 x 3]> <bch:tm [1,000]> <tibble [1,000 x 3]>
```

Benchmarks can certainly be evil, especially when the data the benchmark uses is not representative of real data (either in class or size/dimensions). However, from this it seems somewhat clear that `rowSums` by itself is clearly the fastest (high `` `itr/sec` ``) and close to the most memory-lean (low `mem_alloc`).

Since they all derive the same output (`bench::mark` defaults to `check=TRUE`, which ensures that all outputs are the same), I believe this is a reasonable comparison of strengths and such. From here, which makes the most sense? Code-goodness is not just about correct output, it's also about readability and maintainability, especially when future-self might not recall all context of why some obscure less-readable code was chosen over more direct and declarative code.

Comment: It looks drastically different when the number of rows increases (for example to 15,000). All per rows solutions slow down dramatically.

Comment: @Marek, that's expected, not surprising. It's also why in R, vectorized solutions are almost always the more efficient way to go.

Comment: Still worth mentioning because data.table is usually used for large tables.